# COMO OBTENER ULTIMO REGISTRO DEL MES ANTERIOR MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la tabla de nombre **"servicios"** de la cual deseo obtener el ultimo registro del mes anterior donde el **"sg_vehiculo"** es igual al valor que le asigne.

En otras consultas yo hago esto:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM servicios WHERE MONTH(sg_fecha_registro) = '$filter_mes' AND YEAR(sg_fecha_registro) = '$filter_anio'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Pero lo que deseo en este caso es que automáticamente me detecte el mes anterior sin enviar un dato mediante POST o GET.

**¿Como puedo realizar eso?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Todavía la pregunta no queda clara. ¿Quieres que la consulta te traiga una fila que sería el último registro del mes anterior? ¿O sea, en este caso quieres el último registro de enero de 2019? ¿Cuál es el campo que determina que es el último registro, la misma fecha o es el campo `sg_id`?

Comment: Lo que quiero es que la consulta traiga la fila que sería el último registro del mes anterior, el campo determinante seria `sg_fecha_registro`.

Comment: Prueba esta consulta: `SELECT * FROM servicios WHERE MONTH(sg_fecha_registro) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND YEAR(sg_fecha_registro) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) ORDER BY sg_fecha_registro DESC LIMIT 1` ahí los datos se ordenan de forma DESCendente por el campo `sg_fecha_registro` ya que dices que los quieres ordenados por esa fecha y el `LIMIT 1` te trae una sola fila, que es lo que quieres según lo enunciado en tu pregunta.

Comment: Funciona correctamente @A.Cedano Muchas Gracias, si deseas podrias ponerlo como respuesta para poder puntuarlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algo asi debería funcionar, incluso cuando el ultimo mes corresponde al año anterior (cuando enero es el mes en curso):

```
SELECT * FROM servicios
WHERE YEAR(sg_fecha_registro) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(sg_fecha_registro) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND sg_vehiculo = 1
ORDER BY sg_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Para traer el último registro, estoy usando el id, ya que no tienes un campo con la hora (lo ideal)

Comment: Voy a probarlo ahora mismo y te aviso si me funcionó, muchas gracias

Comment: No funciona la consulta en MySQL, de alguna manera gracias, y encontré un error en tu respuesta, utilizas doblemente el WHERE.

Comment: @JairB. esta consulta también debería funcionar, lo que pasa es que hay que cambiar esto: `WHERE sg_vehiculo = 1` por esto `AND sg_vehiculo = 1`, en caso de querer un filtro por ese campo. Y si quieres que el orden sea por fecha, cambiarlo igualmente en el `ORDER BY`

Comment: Si, lo acabo de volver a revisar y es correcto, tanto tu respuesta como la de @GabrielMoreyra funcionan

Comment: @JairB. puedes marcar esta respuesta como aceptada, puesto que ya está redactada y es correcta, a condición de que Gabriel corrija el error que hay debido al doble `WHERE`. No tiene sentido escribir otra respuesta que es casi idéntica. En la mía uso `DATE_SUB` y aquí la resta se hace con el operador `-`, en la mía uso `NOW()` y aquí `CURRENT_DATE`. Son maneras distintas de llegar a un mismo resultado.

Comment: Esta bien, muchas gracias por la ayuda @A.Cedano , estaré al tanto de la corrección de Gabriel para poder aceptarla como respuesta.

Comment: Perdon, no me habia dado cuenta del error.. corregido! Gracias!

Comment: Muchas Gracias @GabrielMoreyra , tu respuesta fue aceptada.